# What i can do with ��� PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have code which determines whether or not a palindrome string.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=pal.php method="get">
<input type="text" name="str">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['str']))
{$k=0;$n=0;
     $xr=$_GET['str'];

    if($xr == convert_cyr_string($xr , 'w' , 'k'))
    {
        $n=1;
    }
    else
        $n=2;

     $x=str_replace(" ","",$xr);

    echo "dlina: ".strlen($x)/$n."<br>";

        for ($i=0;$i<strlen($x)/$n;$i++)
          {
        #echo $x[$i]."<br>";

             if ($x[$i]==$x[strlen($x)/$n-$i-1])
             $k++;
              echo $x[$i]."<br>";
           }
           if ($k==strlen($x)/$n)
            echo "PALINDROM";
            else echo "ne palindrom<br>";



    $backurl="http://s2.localhost/project1/php/send_list/pal.php";
    print "<script language='Javascript'><!--
function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 10000);
//--></script>";
}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem: code works only with english symbols. with cyrillic symbols it's always print � when i printing string symbol by symbol. Respectively, code can't find palindrome in string which entered on russian language.

Answer (score 4):

That's because UTF-8 is a **multibyte** encoding, and you are working on **single byte**.

```
$string = 'aйb';
echo $string[3]; // b
echo $string[2]; // �
echo $string[1]; // �
echo $string[0]; // a
```

In this example `й` is encoded using two byte. If you read them in reverse order you corrupt the string.

You should use the [mb extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php), `mb_strlen` to count the characters (instead of the bytes with `strlen`)  and `mb_substr` to get single character  of the string to build its palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Save your php file as utf-8 instead of ansi.

Comment: you need to provide a better answer. Why will this solve the problem, and how is it done? Provide details.